# CSS attribute selector bug in IE8?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-selectors

as specified by [CSS 2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors):

```
input[type=submit] {
}
```

or

```
input[type="submit"] {
}
```

must matches any input element whose "type" attribute value is exactly equal to "submit". However this selector doesn't works on IE8 (and IE7 compatibility mode). 
Any hint? workarounds?

Comment: it should work in IE8... are you sure there isn't another selector that is being applied?

Comment: the same selector works in google chrome (stable)

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185549/css-attribute-selector-for-input-typebutton-not-working-on-ie7/3386459#3386459 Check to make sure you have a DOCTYPE defined at the top of your page.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

jQuery will give you the selectors you need without dirty hacks.

```
$(':submit').css( 'styleprop', 'value' );
```

Example:

```
$(':submit').css('color','red');
```

Comment: using jQuery to resolve CSS bugs is not very clever. it's like a potholes patching..

Answer (score 1):

internet explorer doesn't retroactively apply styles though.

and the use of those jquery selectors only applies to elements present before that code is run.

anything created and inserted into the DOM afterwards won't be affected by that code.

Answer (score 1):

To answer to your post’s title —not precisely your case—, I’ve just experiment a bug on IE8 :

*I was working on the integration of an ASP.net project where pages names starts by a capital…*

and…

**WITH THIS FORM**

```
<form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="Default.aspx" onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" id="aspnetForm">
```

**Internet Explorer 8** distinguish

```
form[action^="Default"]
```

Value : **D**efault → **don’t work** (but work on IE11 and modern browsers…)

and

```
form[action^="default"]
```

Value : **d**efault → **WORK**

Answer (score 0):

you can use
input[type='submit'] {
code here...
}
hopefully this is working in IE as well as older IE.

Comment: in IE support attribute seletor with single coma ' .