# Css attribute selector for input type="button" not working on IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, css-selectors

I am working on a big form and it contains a lot of buttons all over the form, therefore I am trying to get working input[type="button"] in my main css file so it would catch all buttons with out having to add a class to every single one, for some reason this is not working on IE7, after checking on the web it says that IE7 should be supporting this.

Also it has to be type="button" and not type="submit" as not all buttons will submit the form.

Could anybody give a hint what am I doing wrong?

```
input[type="button"] {
    text-align:center;
}
```

I have also tried `input[type=button]`

Comment: This may be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112783/attribute-selectors-javascript-and-ie8

Comment: I have written [an article](http://sarfraznawaz.wordpress.com/2010/02/22/css-attribute-selector/) with some detailed info about CSS attribute selectors.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I was struggling getting `input[type=button]` selectors working in IE7 or IE8. The problem turned out to be that the HTML Pages were missing a "!DOCTYPE" declaration. Once I added

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

Then everything worked fine. You can obviously use a different "!DOCTYPE" declaration to suit your requirements.

Comment: iv'e  noticed that an .aspx !DOCTYPE is as follows :

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

where would you add the html part that you suggest ? should i replace the XHTML 1.0 with it ?

Comment: I presumed that having any sort of `DOCTYPE` defined would lead to the selectors working. Are they not working for you with the doctype you list above?

Comment: it doesn't work , but come to think of it i checked it only on Google chrome .(maybe it's specific to the browser)

Answer (score 12):

```
input[type="button"]{ text-align:center; }
```

What do you expect that to do? The text in an `<input type="button">` is already centered by default.

If you want to align the button itself within the parent, you have to set `text-align` on the parent element, not the button.

Attribute selectors — with or without quotes — do work on IE7. It's IE6 that's the problem browser there.

Answer (score 3):

I've had no problems getting css statements like that working in IE7; IE6 is always the problem but I believe this CSS would work in there as well.  So I don't think IE7 is the problem.

The first thing is that your CSS sample will only affect buttons, it will not affect submit buttons.  But that's an easy fix; change your css to:

```
input[type="submit"], input[Type="button"]
{ text-align: center; }
```

Second, as Manolo Santos said, could you have another CSS statement that is overriding the text-align setting?  A setting on just input elements?  It's probably worth using a developer tool like Firebug or the developer components built into Chrome or IE8 to help find the CSS problem.

Answer (score 1):

Attribute selectors are, unfortunately, not yet well implemented in all major browsers, because it is CSS3 and not 2.1, the current standard. Because the guys over at W3C are not that quick in making decisions, you better not set your hopes too high, because we won't be able to use css3 any time soon. Some aspects of it are already implemented, but this one isn't (surely not in IE6).

So, as you already said yourself, it would be much better to provide all of your inputs with a class, and make it a habit to do so every time you create a form. It's always handy and not a lot of work when you are already programming the form.

When I create a form, I always add the type of an input as a class, e.g.:

Especially the last two will come in handy in a lot of cases, because you don't háve to style the .button and .submit separately, but you cóuld if you would like to do so.

Comment: +1. It may be worth noting that if the OP does not want to add classes, he can do something like this with javascript or a js framework like jQuery. :)

Comment: Attribute selectors are CSS 2, not 3, and have been a full W3 ‘Recommendation’ for a long time. (Even CSS3 Selectors are a ‘Proposed Recommendation’, which is pretty far along and well-implemented outside of the world of IE!)

Comment: Allright, my mistake, but still it does not change the fact it isn't well implemented yet, because the 'world of IE' as you call it, is still a big world to deal with nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

They work for me in IE7 (both forms, with and without quotes).

Maybe there's another selector that is masking yours. You could try making your selector more specific in order to give it more priority, e.g.:

```
body form input[type="button"] {
background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure everybody is aware of the fact that the solution of adding a !DockType to the header isn't a possibility all the time.

For instance, I develop in DotNetNuke (DNN) environment which the developer doesn't have an access to the header. Then it makes it almost impossible to add !DocType.

In this case you don’t have too much of an option except relating a CssClass to the button and referring to it, explicitly, in the CSS module.

Answer (score 0):

This question is old but if someone have a related problem.. I spend a few minutes trying to solve a similiar problem

input[type="Submit"] doesn't work on IE7 (despite of IE assigning the style correctly to the input as I saw in dev tools).

SOLUTION: I switched from **Submit** to **submit** and it worked!

I posted this here because it may help someone when debugging.

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, there are times when attribute selectors will not apply before the page is displayed in IE7.  This actually just happened to me.  My selector was `table[bgColor="#c0c0c0"]` and would not apply on page load.  Since I was using IE9 (Browser Mode: IE7, Document Mode: IE7 Standards), I was able to use F12 Developer Tools to look at my CSS file. I unchecked the selector and then checked it again.  The attributes applied after that.  This is reproducible exactly in good ol' IE7, so I'm going to have to find a work-around. (Note: Neither using single, double, or no quotes nor making variations in capitalization make an impact here.)