# Css attribute selector for inputs not working in IE8

Tags: html, css, input

I have the following css code working in Firefox/Chrome but not in IE8

```
input[type='text']
{
    float: right;
    width: 170px;
}
```

If I remove the attribute selector, it works in IE but it applies to all the inputs, which I dont want.

```
input
{
    float: right;
    width: 170px;
}
```

I thought attribute selectors were supported in IE8, so I don't know what the problem is.
It is not a matter of the code inside the input, from the moment I use the attribute selector, that css rule will not work whatever code is inside.

EDIT: Css rules for input[type="button"] and input[type="submit"] DO work, but for input[type="text"] DO NOT work. I'm really confused right now.

Comment: So your relevant `input` elements have the attribute `type=text`, or is it defaulted? Please post a complete self-contained example (an HTML document) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 5):

IE7 and IE8 support attribute selectors only if a !DOCTYPE is specified. Attribute selection is NOT supported in IE6 and lower.

Comment: Its working at my end. Can you share your erroneous code on jsfiddle??

Comment: OK, there was an error with the initial html tag, and the !DOCTYPE declaration. Now it works.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

According to http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/css3attributeselectors#compatibilitysection
attribute selectors are quite buggy in IE8

You might want to try just using classes on those input fields you want to select

Answer (score 0):

Go to this **[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1148531/css-attribute-selector-bug-in-ie8)**

Used to jquery

As like this

```
$('input[type="text"]').css({float: 'right'});
```